# Hello i am recieving nullpointer exception when i try to make a .setText(); How can i solve it?

Tags: android

Hello i am getting this exception when i execute the code.I will be so thankful if someone can help me,i cannot find the solution and i am new here.Tell me if something is incomplete.I keep you here the error is giving me in the logcat.

```
    09-20 10:36:44.748  20241-20241/com.pepeermaligno.aplicattionwith2activities E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pepeermaligno.aplicattionwith2activities, PID: 20241
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pepeermaligno.aplicattionwith2activities/com.pepeermaligno.aplicattionwith2activities.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    atcom.pepeermaligno.aplicattionwith2activities.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:27)
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button boton;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        boton.setOnClickListener(this);    
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.boton:
                String dato = editText.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("DATO",dato);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }
    }
    }
///////////////////

    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if(extras!=null){

        String dato = extras.getString("DATO");  //here dato= "The String i put in the editText".

            texto.setText(dato);    // Here its the fail,it said texto=null 
        }

    }
```

Thanks .

Comment: make sure you have defined `text` in `activity_second.xml`

Comment: Means `texto` is `null`

Comment: Are you sure that you are finding the object by its correct Id? I'd double check that.

Comment: Yes this is at my activity_second.xml

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: Ok thankss i was calling bad the findViewbyId(R.id.texto).I will give you points and thanks for the time.